# How to customize the constructor in Objective C programming?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Recently I am doing a project on iOS, I have created a class, namely `YellowTileView`, I would like to do something like when I clicked on button, a new tile will be shown

```
-(IBAction)ShowImage:(id)sender
{
   YellowTileView *yt=[[YellowTileView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 80)];
   [self.view addSubview:yt];
}
```

This work fine for me. But the next step is to take a integer number that randomized by another method.

My question is can I redefine/create the method `initWithFrame` by myself? If yes, how can I do this and would it be any problems as I have some drawing code in the class `YellowTileView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you should know that you can reimplement all methods of parent. So you can reimplement initialization method of UIView defined like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
```

But you can also create your own initialization method with your own parameters list.

In .h file:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andWithRandomInt:(int)random;
```

And in .m file:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andWithRandomInt:(int)random {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        _random = random;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely can - it should look something like this :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andNumber:(int)number {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        myNumber = number;
    }

    return self;
}
```

As long as you call a `super init...` method somewhere in your constructor you'll be fine.

Comment: So may I know can I do it in this way:
        `-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andNumber:(int)number{
         self =[super initWithFrame:frame andNumber:number];
         
         if (self){
            myNumber=number;
          }`

Comment: No - your super class doesn't have an `initWithFrame:andNumber:` method - see my edited answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, it's common practice to name your methods like this:

```
-(IBAction)showImage:(id)sender
```

So, methods names start with a lowercase letter. Note that you don't have to - it's just that all the other developers do that.

Comment: If nothing else, it makes you look like an old hand at Objective-C :-) For the historical perspective, camel case starting with a lower case was/is the standard used in Smalltalk-80, the inspiration for the "Objective" part of Objective-C.

Comment: yeah well I'm coming from the NeXTSTEP-era of Objective-C, so @Monolo is very right ;-)